# C - effect of a write() to a closed tcp connection when using signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

Tags: sockets, tcp

By closed connection I mean that the other end closed it gracefully.
I would expect to receive a 0 from the `write()` as returned value, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact behavior may depend on underlying OS but in general you should get an error, i.e., `write` will return `-1` and set `errno` (to `ECONNRESET` for instance).

Comment: I just tested it on my linux machine, and it returns a value > 0 ! (ie the number of characters it thinks it wrote)

Comment: It's normal to be able to write at least once more; and you can get even more in some cases.  On an old BSD system, connecting just to my own local machine, I get one successful write followed by a -1 with errno set to `EPIPE`.  On a more modern Linux box I get the same thing.  This is because it takes one extra TCP round-trip for the sender to "see" that the receiver has gone away.  Setting `SO_KEEPALIVE` should cause an earlier discovery but it can take a long time (RFC-1122 says at least 2 hours!).